# How to solve The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 padding-right">
                <div id="bookListDiv">
                    <!--features_items -->
                    <h2 class="title text-center">Features Items</h2>
                    @{Html.RenderAction("ProductList", "Product", new { Model = Model });}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Inside the view as you can see that I have rendered an action which is below:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ProductList(List<Product> Model)
        {
            return PartialView(Model);
        }
```

The action above calls for a partial `ProductList` Partial view, this here below:

```
@model List<EShopperTheme.Domain.Entities.Product>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID })" alt="" />
                    <h2>@item.ProductCategory</h2>
                    <h2>@item.ProductPrice AFN</h2>
                    <p>@item.ProductName</p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <img src="@Url.Action("GetSecondPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID })" alt="" />
                        <h2>@item.ProductPrice AFN</h2>
                        <p>@Html.ActionLink(item.ProductName, "ProductDetails", new { item.ProductID })</p>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProductID)
                            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" value="Add to cart" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As you can see in the partial I have a form and inside the form there is button type of submit `AddToCart`. The problem is when I click on add to cart button while running the application I get this Error. 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type

```
'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(EShopperTheme.Domain.Entities.Cart, Int32, System.String)' in 'EShopperTheme.Controllers.CartController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

The action `AddToCart` in my cart controller is below:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
        }
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: From what I can see, you are generating form for each product which could be causing an issue. To isolate this try doing this for one product for example `Model.Take(1)` in foreach loop.

Comment: @CrnaStena On Where?

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.Take(1))`. But let me ask you this. Is this supposed to add item to cart then reload the same page? If so, I would point you in direction of using Ajax posts for such purpose. See this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8) for older version of MVC, principle would be similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CrnaStena it just shows one product and while clicking on the add to cart still gives that damn error!

Comment: Did you try changing `@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProductID)` to `@Html.Hidden("productId", item.ProductID)`?

Comment: @CrnaStena sucha genius guy, where do you learn all these about? lol... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use of `@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProductID)` generate a hidden input with

```
<input type="hidden" name="item.ProductID" .. />
```

but it would need to be `name="ProductID". Delete the input and instead use a route value in the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new { ProductID = item.ProductID} ))
```

Alternatively you could use

```
@Html.Hidden("ProductID", item.ProductID)
```

Side note: You child action is unnecessary, and you could just use `@{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductList", Model;}` in the view

Comment: The first is better (and you should also add the return url as a route parameter. The hidden inputs are unnecessary and its creating invalid html unless you also use `new { id = "" }` to remove the duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: Hey Stephen, when do you sleep? So I can answer few questions while you do it. :)

Comment: Exactly! i just encountered another big hit, as you can see i have infinite scroll when i scroll down and add a product to the cart it just goes well but when i click on continue shopping which takes the return url i am being redirected to the infinitecontrol any clue, how overcome this one?

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing in your question about an _infinite scroll_. You will need to ask a new question explaining the issue and showing the relevant code. Note also you need to remove `Cart cart` from your method parameter - you r not posting any values associated with `Cart` and all you doing is adding the product to it, then tossing it away. I assume you want the cart to be in `Session`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ProductID)
```

to

```
@Html.Hidden("productId", item.ProductID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a good suggestion but i already received the answer. :)